# How to set up an VPN Server which directs a connected users browser requests to one specific domain to another IP address?

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, forwarding

I'm about to create a testing environment for my clients, which have to access certain web addresses.

What I want to achieve is the following:

- A client connects to the VPN server
- He opens a browser and accesses the page example.de
- While connected to the VPN the example.de host should point to x.x.x.x in difference to y.y.y.y while not connected

Can you point me into the right direction?

Comment: off the top of my head, a DNS server?

Comment: Yeah, that was what I thought. But how to make the VPN server add the custom DNS server for all requests?

Comment: VPN and DNS are two completely separate systems. The VPN server has nothing to do with DNS. Your DNS server lives on its own, and is configured on its own.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up! I need two separate servers then :)

Comment: Depending on the VPN server/client software, there might be an option to override the client's DNS server setting. You would make the setting point to your own DNS server, which would then return data like you want. You should also make sure recursive DNS lookups for other zones work too.